# How to enumerate all SQS queues in an AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

How do I list all SQS queues in an AWS account programmatically via the API and .Net SDK?

I am already doing something similar with DynamoDb  tables, and that's fairly straightforward - you can page through results using [ListTables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html) in a loop until you have them all.

However the equivalent SQS Api endpoint, [ListQueues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ListQueues.html) is different and not as useful. It returns up to 1000 queues, with no option of paging.

Yes, there can be over 1000 queues in my case. I have had a query return exactly 1000 results. It's all in 1 region, so it's not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014928/aws-sqs-queues-dont-list-all-queues).

Comment: You could use the `QueueNamePrefix` parameter to simulate paging of the names, especially if you know the general format of your Queue names. Not a perfect solution, but might meet your needs.

Comment: Yeah, we know that the Queue names all start with the same prefix. This is not an approach that is easy to make general and efficient, not without some quite complicated text analysis.

Answer (score 6):

You can retrieve SQS queue names from Cloudwatch, which supports paging. It will only return queues that are considered active.

An active queue is [described as](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MonitorSQSwithCloudWatch.html):

> A queue is considered active by CloudWatch for up to six hours from
>   the last activity (for example, any API call) on the queue.

Something like this should work:

```
var client = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
string nextToken = null;
var results = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

do
{
    var result = client.ListMetrics(new ListMetricsRequest()
    {
        MetricName = "ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage",
        NextToken = nextToken
    });

    results = results.Concat(
        result
        .Metrics
        .SelectMany(x => x.Dimensions.Where(d => d.Name == "QueueName")
        .Select(d => d.Value))
    );

    nextToken = result.NextToken;

} while (nextToken != null);
```